# How we can read 16 un signed integer(16 uint) jpeg files in python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

How we can read the 16 uint jpeg images in python 
please suggest me the libraries which can read the these type of files in python.
i tried matplotlib, scipy, scikit-image, medpy ,Pil ,opencv, numpy libraries. 
when we are using these libraries i am getting the out put as:

```
raise IOError("cannot identify image file")

IOError: cannot identify image file
```

please help me

find the file from the link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4l5GiM7kBXraDEyMXdseENfUlE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where did you get the 16-bit JPEG:s from? As far as I know, there is no such thing as a 16-bit JPEG in the standard (there is 12-bit variant, though). Could it be something else than JPEG?

Comment: its a medical image and i need to read its pixal value

Comment: find the file from the link


https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4l5GiM7kBXraDEyMXdseENfUlE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like it is created by Accusoft who seem to have tools that process such things... http://www.accusoft.com/picmedxopcodes.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having 16-bit JPEG images sounds a bit strange, as the JPEG standard does not support 16-bit images. It has 12-bit images, though. Unfortunately, most readers only support the usual 8-bits/pixel RGB images, so even with the 12-bit images this may be a bit challenging.

One useful test could be to try:

```
hdr = open("myimage.jpeg", "rb").read(2)
print "{:02x} {:02x}".format(ord(hdr[0]), ord(hdr[1]))
```

If your file is a JPEG file, it should start with:

```
ff d8
```

If you do not get those, then the file is something else. Is there any program you can use to open the file? Which program produced the files?

Comment: i was able read image using these code.
but i need to read the each pixalvalue of this image for a project based on medical domain.so please help me to print its actual pixal value array of this image. thanks for your support

Comment: this image can read by mathlab and th output shows below
 i = imfinfo('di.jpg')

i = 

           Filename: [1x56 char]
        FileModDate: '14-Jul-2014 15:22:13'
           FileSize: 1044064
             Format: 'jpg'
      FormatVersion: ''
              Width: 1024
             Height: 1024
           BitDepth: 16
          ColorType: 'grayscale'
    FormatSignature: ''
    NumberOfSamples: 1
       CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
      CodingProcess: 'Lossless'
            Comment: {'Created by AccuSoft Corp.'}

Comment: find the file from the link


https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4l5GiM7kBXraDEyMXdseENfUlE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard for 16bits grayscale lossless jpeg (recommendations ITU-T T.81). Now replaced with JPEG-LS and JPEG-2000.

This specific type of JPEG has single channel grayscale on a 16bits wide word, unlike 3 components RGB one on a 24bits/8 bits per channel.

Try using thorfdbg's libjpeg as it supports this type of old jpeg standard: https://github.com/thorfdbg/libjpeg